# New unified Windows Dev Center - how to unpublish/hide/delete app?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-store

I have a problem with this new unified Windows Dev Center. In old version, there wasn't any problems to delete or hide app from Windows Phone store.

But in this new interface.. I cannot find that option.

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/overview?from=UHF

Of course, I tried to find some information how to do it - I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/en-en/library/windows/apps/jj193601.aspx), but it is totally useless.

> This topic applies to the earlier Windows Store dashboard and not the new unified Windows Dev Center dashboard.

Nice one, very userfriendly.

To conclude - how to delete or hide or just unpublish my app from WindowsPhone store using new Windows Dev Center?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Select your app from the dashboard, go to submissions and click update to create a new submission (yes counter intuitive) and then go to pricing and availability and scroll down to Distribution and visibility and click on show options.
Then select hide this app and stop selling, save it and submit it.

Answer (score 3):

The new dev center is in preview mode(read only), so I think that you will have this feature when the account migrations are finished. Until then, you also can't publish new apps.
You can find more info here: http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/dev-center-account-migration-begins-next-week/